# Which modifier should I choose 'bootleg/bootlegging/bootlegger wars'?

Tags: word-request

One gang is engaged in a violent conflict with another gang because of competing interests in making profits from selling illegal alcoholic beverages. What do you call that?

Suppose, it's

> There were bootleg wars during the Prohibition in the US.

Which modifier should I choose 'bootleg/bootlegging/bootlegger wars'?

Google gives hardly any search results for all of them. What else then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem in using *bootleg wars.* Vannie Higgins was a mobster and a prominent bootlegger.

The [page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vannie_Higgins) has the whole section under the title -

> **Manhattan bootleg wars**

Another possibility is bootleggers wars, but you may need an apostrophe

> "*bootleggers' wars"*

[A google book says](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=W3ypQ0NGrTMC&pg=PA95&lpg=PA95&dq=%22bootleggers%27%20wars%22&source=bl&ots=azHQt8y-L6&sig=ACfU3U0Kas5yC8Bbo-4ELJfjK7xQ7xr4RA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEytr8747mAhXV73MBHVcrA0cQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22bootleggers'%20wars%22&f=false):

> St Louis was wide open to *the bootleggers' wars*

Comment: What about the other two?

Comment: I already said about it - the one with an apostrophe. And, *bootlegging wars* is also fine. [***Chicago's bootlegging wars***](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=tMlbrI2sFn8C&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=%22bootlegging+wars%22&source=bl&ots=FxkYs34KSa&sig=ACfU3U2M9ithnzxmEacBZ6FaLSbQcPkLzQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7ooLF_Y7mAhW36nMBHaT8BZcQ6AEwD3oECAwQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22bootlegging%20wars%22&f=false) is quite known.

Comment: What about 'bootlegger wars'? Is it wrong?