# What should I choose as a modifier: a member of a group or activity?

Tags: grammar, modifiers

If I want to construct a phrase meaning "people who teamed up to engage in some specific activity" (in my case, illegal activity), what should I choose as a modifier: a word for the activity or a word denoting a member of that group?

For example, 'racketeering gang' (or 'racket gang') or 'racketeer gang'? I already asked [a similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/230276/which-modifier-should-i-choose-bootleg-bootlegging-bootlegger-wars), but, for some reason, nobody answered it

Comment: There's another way of boosting the question. Offer some bounty. It happens in some cases that the question does not attract any attention.

Comment: I answered it [there](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/230276/which-modifier-should-i-choose-bootleg-bootlegging-bootlegger-wars/231202#231202).

Comment: It could be either.  "racketeering gang" has more use than "rackteer gang", but "biker gang" or "bike gang" and not "biking gang".  Also a lot of times the idiomatic phrase has a possessive:  "steamfitter's union". "liar's club", etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which modifier should I choose 'bootleg/bootlegging/bootlegger wars'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/230276/which-modifier-should-i-choose-bootleg-bootlegging-bootlegger-wars)